# SHOW TABLES not returning correct items in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have multiple tables named like so MOM2016, MOM2017, MOM2018.

When i run query in phpmyadmin

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'MOM%'
```

it returns 3 items as expected.

BUT!!!! When i run in php, my code seem to give me only 1 item in the array (first one only MOM2016).

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'MOM%'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$dbArray = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo "DEBUG:".count($dbArray);
```

This give:

> DEBUG:1

My php code is wrong? Pls help.

Comment: that is an array, holding one result, i.e. 1

Comment: ok i will rephrase question.

Comment: you don't need to, you need to iterate through your result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all the results at once,

```
$dbArray = $result->fetch_all();
echo "DEBUG:".count($dbArray);
```

Comment: I get 3 count too. But how do I access the items in array? i tried print dbArray[0] and it prints "Array" only.

Comment: fetch_all will return an array of arrays, so the table names are in $dbArray[0][0], $dbArray[1][0], $dbArray[2][0]. The same applies to the other poster's answer.

Comment: I guess this is basic stuff that I do not know. Thank you this works now. Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through your fetch resource

```
$dbArray = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $dbArray[] = $row;
}

print "DEBUG: " . count($dbArray);
```

Comment: by this way i get count 3. but the content of dbArray is [Array, Array, Array].